# Is the digital root of twin primes product larger than (3,5) always 8

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Is the digital root of twin primes product larger than $(3,5)$ always $8$?

E.g. I just checked the following and it is true was wondering if it is more widely true

$5\times 7=35$, digital root $=3+5=8$
$11\times 13=143$, digital root $=1+4+3=8$
$17\times 19=323$, digital root $=3+2+3=8$
$101\times 103=10403$, digital root $=1+0+4+0+3=8$

Comment: Yes. The digital root equals the remainder when divided by $9$; and all prime pairs apart from $(3,5)$ are of the form $(3n-1,3n+1)$.

Answer (score 18):

One of the basic [properties](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twin_prime#Properties) of twin primes $k-1$, $k+1$ is that $k$ must be a multiple of $6$ (except $k=4$).  Set $k=6t$, and we have $$(k-1)(k+1)=(6t+1)(6t-1)=36t-1$$

Hence the product of any pair of twin primes (except $3,5$) will be congruent to $-1$ modulo $9$.  Hence the [digital root](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_root#Congruence_formula) of same will be $8\equiv -1\pmod{9}$.

Answer (score 4):

Let $p$ and $p+2$ be twin primes with $p\gt 3$. Then $p$ is congruent to one of $2, 5, 8$ mod $9$. In each case $p(p+2)\equiv 8\pmod{9}$.

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a "Proof By Construction for the Digital Root Sequencing of Twin Primes" that contextualizes the twins and answers your question: http://www.primesdemystified.com/twinprimesdigitalrootproof

Comment: This should be a comment